# Actionscript: TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter Constructor Failed must be non-null

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, nullreferenceexception

I get the following exception when running my flash app in a browser using the debugging plugin under debian linux. I cannot replicate the exception when I run the app in FlashBuilder (under windows 7) with or without the debugger.

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter Constructor Failed must be non-null.
    at flash.globalization::Collator/ctor()
    at flash.globalization::Collator()
    at spark.globalization.supportClasses::CollatorBase/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::createWorkingInstance()
    at spark.globalization.supportClasses::GlobalizationBase/localeChanged()
    at spark.globalization.supportClasses::GlobalizationBase/setStyle()
    at spark.collections::SortField/get stringCollator()
    at spark.collections::SortField/stringCompare()
    at spark.collections::Sort/internalCompare()
    at Array$/_sort()
    at Array/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::sort()
    at spark.collections::Sort/sort()
    at mx.collections::ListCollectionView/internalRefresh()
    at mx.collections::ListCollectionView/refresh()
    at com.xxx.yyy.model.proxy::RemoteIOProxy/handlePossibleInputs()
    at com.xxx.yyy.model.proxy::RemoteIOProxy/handleGetResponse()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at com.xxx.yyy.model.message::ResponseFactory/createResponse()
    at com.xxx.yyy.model.proxy::ConnectionProxy/handleData()
```

I'm not sure what this exception means. It looks like a "Parameter x must be non-null." exception except that would suggest the parameter is named "Constructor Failed" which doesn't really make sense.

I believe that the offending code is in this block someplace, however, I don't know how to make the vm spit out line numbers in stack traces.

```
// possibleInputs is a populated ArrayCollection
var sort:Sort = new Sort();
var sortField:SortField = new SortField("name");
sort.fields = [sortField];
possibleInputs.sort = sort;
possibleInputs.refresh();
```

Comment: Can you step through your code while debugging and see exactly on which statement the exception is thrown?

Comment: The exception does not get thrown when I run the application on my dev box (windows 7). Only when I run the app on a deployed system (debian). If there is a way to connect the FlashBuilder's debugger to a flash vm running remotely, I can't find it.

Comment: What's the player version on client?

Comment: from the readme: Adobe Systems Incorporated
Flash Player 11 for Linux
Version 11.2.202.359
2012